# How do I add a new record to objectStateEntryList in SaveChanges override

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I have several entities that contain datetime fields for EffectiveAsOf and ExpiredAsOf.  When an entity is modified I want to override the SaveChanges method and rather than just update the existing entity have the code save the original record back to the database with an ExpiredAsOf datetime set to the current time, and a new record inserted with the new data and EffectiveAsOf set to the current time with ExpiredAsOf set to null.

I know that the ObjectStateEntry items in the objectStateEntryList contain CurrentValues and Original values objects, as well as an Entity object.  What does EF use to write data to the DB the CurrentValues data or the Entity?  How do I go about creating a new entry?  Or, am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

I know that I can handle this in the entities outside of EF, but would rather have EF detect and handle these entities automatically.

Thanks in advance for your help and insight,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF by default will use both - it uses original values to check for a concurrency issue (i.e. if the record has changed since you loaded the data from the DB) then uses the entity's current/modified values to update the DB record.

It is not possible to have EF "detect and handle these entities automatically".  You will need to create a new instance of the entity object, copy the values from the existing entity object, set the appropriate effective and expired dates on both objects, add the new entity object to the DbContext, then save changes.  The best place to do this is by overriding the SaveChanges() method of your DbContext.  To keep it as clean and manageable as possible, I suggest using the repository pattern.